# Where is my twig template getting its variables?

Tags: php, symfony, drupal, twig

I am trying to sort of reverse engineer to this twig template to get back to where the the variables are being set in the first place so I can add more variables. This is a Drupal8 project. The beginning of the twig template **"node--course.html.twig"** is seen below. Its where I see the variables being set.

```
{#
/**
 * @file
 * Default theme implementation to display a node.
 *
 * Available variables:
 * - node: Full node entity.
 *   - id: The node ID.
 *   - bundle: The type of the node, for example, "page" or "article".
 *   - authorid: The user ID of the node author.
 *   - createdtime: Time the node was published formatted in Unix timestamp.
 *   - changedtime: Time the node was changed formatted in Unix timestamp.
 * - label: The title of the node.
 * - content: All node items. Use {{ content }} to print them all,
 *   or print a subset such as {{ content.field_example }}. Use
 *   {{ content|without('field_example') }} to temporarily suppress the printing
 *   of a given child element.
 * - author_picture: The node author user entity, rendered using the "compact"
 *   view mode.
 * - metadata: Metadata for this node.
 * - date: Themed creation date field.
 * - author_name: Themed author name field.
 * - url: Direct URL of the current node.
 * - display_submitted: Whether submission information should be displayed.
 * - attributes: HTML attributes for the containing element.
 *   The attributes.class element may contain one or more of the following
 *   classes:
 *   - node: The current template type (also known as a "theming hook").
 *   - node--type-[type]: The current node type. For example, if the node is an
 *     "Article" it would result in "node--type-article". Note that the machine
 *     name will often be in a short form of the human readable label.
 *   - node--view-mode-[view_mode]: The View Mode of the node; for example, a
 *     teaser would result in: "node--view-mode-teaser", and
 *     full: "node--view-mode-full".
 *   The following are controlled through the node publishing options.
 *   - node--promoted: Appears on nodes promoted to the front page.
 *   - node--sticky: Appears on nodes ordered above other non-sticky nodes in
 *     teaser listings.
 *   - node--unpublished: Appears on unpublished nodes visible only to site
 *     admins.
 * - title_attributes: Same as attributes, except applied to the main title
 *   tag that appears in the template.
 * - content_attributes: Same as attributes, except applied to the main
 *   content tag that appears in the template.
 * - author_attributes: Same as attributes, except applied to the author of
 *   the node tag that appears in the template.
 * - title_prefix: Additional output populated by modules, intended to be
 *   displayed in front of the main title tag that appears in the template.
 * - title_suffix: Additional output populated by modules, intended to be
 *   displayed after the main title tag that appears in the template.
 * - view_mode: View mode; for example, "teaser" or "full".
 * - teaser: Flag for the teaser state. Will be true if view_mode is 'teaser'.
 * - page: Flag for the full page state. Will be true if view_mode is 'full'.
 * - readmore: Flag for more state. Will be true if the teaser content of the
 *   node cannot hold the main body content.
 * - logged_in: Flag for authenticated user status. Will be true when the
 *   current user is a logged-in member.
 * - is_admin: Flag for admin user status. Will be true when the current user
 *   is an administrator.
 *
 * @see template_preprocess_node()
 *
 * @todo Remove the id attribute (or make it a class), because if that gets
 *   rendered twice on a page this is invalid CSS for example: two lists
 *   in different view modes.
 *
 * @ingroup themeable
 */
#}

{# {{ kint() }} #}

<article id="node-{{ node.id }}" {{ attributes }}>
{{node}}
  {{ title_prefix }}
  {% if not page %}
    <h2{{ title_attributes }}>
      <a href="{{ url }}" rel="bookmark">{{ label }}</a>
    </h2>
  {% endif %}
  {{ title_suffix }}

  {% if node.field_packaging.value == '1' %}

    {% set image = content.field_image %}
    {% set ce = content.field_tax_credit_hours %}
    {% set goal = content.field_goal %}
    {% set target_audience = content.field_audience %}
    {% set objectives = content.field_objectives %}
    {% set accreditation = content.field_accreditation %}
    {% set disclosure = content.field_disclosure_statement %}
    {# {% set references_old = content.field_references %} #}
    {% set references = content.field_references_par %}
    {% set appendix = content.field_appendix %}
    {% set faculty = content.field_faculty %}
    {% set related_courses = content.field_related_courses %}
    {# set suggested_courses = content.field_suggested_courses #}
    {% set additional = content.field_callout %}
    {% set expiration = node.field_expiration.value %}
```

I have tried taking words that appear to be unique like

> field_tax_credit_hours

And search the project to see maybe where its being set but it only appears in other twig files. I also looked at the whole page as a whole to see maybe I can search for where the output is coming from. For example they very start of my page begins with:

```
<!-- returning result -->
```

When I search that it points me to a php function called getResult()

```
public function getResult() {
       if ($this->rowBase() == "") {
          print "<!-- rowBase empty -->";
          \Drupal\Core\Database\Database::setActiveConnection();
          return false;
       }
       print "<!-- returning result -->";
             $result = $this->connection->query($this->rowBase())->fetchAll();
         \Drupal\Core\Database\Database::setActiveConnection();

       return $result;
    }
```

searching for rowBase() i found this function:

```
 public function rowBase() {


     if (parent::accessCheck()) {

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM learning_courseuser
                  WHERE idUser = " . $_SESSION['public_area_idst'] .
                 " AND idCourse = " . $this->ID. " ";
        return $sql;
       } else {

            return ""; 
       }

    }
```

So it appears to not set the variables I need but instead returns the users info if the are logged in.  So I am now stuck and don't really know where to go from here.  I have been a PHP developer for a year or so and only did a team treehouse drupal course so it was very basic.

I noticed the page also returns this

```
<!-- BEGIN OUTPUT from 'themes/custom/site/templates/node--course.html.twig' -->
```

But searching for the string "BEGIN OUTPUT" returns nothing. So I don't know where to go from here.

It seems that the variables are coming from the "content" object but searching content in the project has WAY too many results to go through. Any ideas where to look would be fantastic.

**UPDATE**

I was asked to look into template_preprocess_node

and got this:

```
function site_preprocess_node(&$variables) {

  $node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node');

  if ($node && $node->getType() == 'course') {
    $noti = new FormaNotification();
    print "HERE";
    print_r($noti->getResult());
    exit;
    if ($noti->getResult()) {
      $variables['signIn'] = "yes";
        if ($noti->getFormaAdmin())
          $variables['is_forma_admin'] = "yes";
        else
        $variables['is_forma_admin'] = "no";
    } else {
      $variables['signIn'] = "no";
      $variables['is_forma_admin'] = "no";

    }

  $current_url = Url::fromRoute('<current>');
    $variables['signURL']  = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $current_url->toString();


   if ($node->get('field_packaging')->getValue()[0]['value'] == '2') {
         $variables['regis'] = true;
   } else {
          $reg = new FormaRegis();
          $reg->setConnection('docebo');

          $reg->setID($node->get('field_docebo_course_id')->getValue()[0]['value']);
           $result = $reg->getResult();

            if(!empty($result)) {
                $variables['regis'] = true;
            } else {
               $variables['regis'] = false;
            }

   }



  } // course


}
```

So looking at it, it appears to have some function of registration sign in  and not the variables

Comment: Search for the name of the template `$template = $twig->load('index.html');` (in this case index.html) Then find where the `render`  method is called `echo $template->render(['the' => 'variables', 'go' => 'here']);`  https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/api.html

Comment: I will do that right now

Comment: a search for "node--course.html" did not bring up anything :(

Comment: search for less, `course`

Comment: and a search for "Twig_Loader_Filesystem" also brought up nothing

Comment: course.html also came up with nothing

Comment: Does `@see template_preprocess_node()` from the template help?

Comment: @kerbholz see update. I don't think its what I am looking for

Comment: Did you chek into CMS?

Comment: @danielarend Im sorry, what do you mean?

Comment: the machine name starting with field_* usually is made when you create a new field into a content type on CMS. Login into cms (/user) and search for structure-> content types -> (your content types) and then manage fields.

Comment: @danielarend There they are! Wow. I would have never thought to look there. If you can move this to the answer I will mark it as solved. One more question though. How does this connect to the database? I am trying to make a field that looks to see if the user has completed n amout of credits and if they go over n amount, they cannot register for more classes.

Comment: Sure, i will. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is into CMS.

The machine name starting with field_* usually is made when you create a new field into a content type on CMS.

Login into cms (/user) and search for structure-> content types -> (your content types) and then manage fields.

You  should find it.

Comment: If I were to set a Boolean value, where it would query the database to see how many credits a student completed on current date. How would I set that? Would it be on the CMS side as well?

Comment: If you create this field in CMS, you can call it into your template file. Usually is content."field_your_machine_name"